# Auto-preenchimento de entrada em um formulário (php, html)

Tags: php, html

Tenho um formulário simples com os seguintes campos do tipo texto: nome, cargo, celular e email. Quero fazer com que ao se preencher o campo 'nome' o campo 'email' seja automaticamente preenchido da seguinte forma: por exemplo, se o campo 'nome' for preenchido com "José da Silva" o campo 'email' se preencheria automaticamente e em tempo real com "jose@dominio.com". Qual a forma mais simples pra chegar a isso?

Meu formulário:

```
    <form name="formulaio" method="post" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>"> 
        <label>
            <span>Nome:</span>
            <input type="text" name="nome" /><br>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>Cargo:</span>
            <input type="text" name="cargo" /><br>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>Celular:</span>
            <input type="text" name="celular" /><br>
        </label>

        <label>
            <span>e-mail:</span>
            <input type="text" name="email" /><br>
        </label>
        <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="enviar" />
        <button type="submit" class="envio" title="Enviar"></button> 
    </form>
```

Answer (score 4):

A forma mais simples seria utilizando jQuery.

Algo como:

```
$( "input[name=nome]").change(function() {
  var nome      = $(this).val();
  var pEspaco   = nome.indexOf(' ');
  var nomeFinal = nome;
  if(pEspaco != -1){
    nomeFinal = nome.substr(0, pEspaco);
  }
  $( "input[name=email]").val( nomeFinal + "@dominio.com.br");
});
```

Perceba que aguardamos a mudança no `input` com nome **nome**.
Quando ocorre um evento de mudança é armazenamos o nome em uma variável e procurar pelo primeiro espaço em branco. Definimos também uma variável chamada `nomeFinal`, caso exista um espaço em branco cortamos a string até o espaço. E por último definimos o valor do `input` com nome **email** para `nomeFinal + uma string`.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo o que entendi, você quer que o campo seja preenchido automaticamente, através do recursos de autocompletar do browser/navegador, o qual já tem um padrão de dados preenchidos anteriormente, e facilitar o preenchimento do Form, correto?

A solução é simples, caso essa seja a circunstância:

- basta adicionar a propriedade `autocomplete="on"`

Exemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="nome" autocomplete="on" />
```